# unable to clear a textbox data

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I'm not able to delete textbox data with the code below

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {            
        if(char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)==false)
        {
            count++;
       }
        if (count == 1)
        {
            textBox1.Text = ("");
            count = 0;
        }
   }
```

tried using `clear` method as well the alphabet i entered stays in the textbox and when i type any key it get overwritten but i want the textbox to be empty the second time and the prev data to be removed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just need to say you've handled the event:

```
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) == false)
        {
            count++;
        }
        if (count == 1)
        {
            textBox1.Text = ("");
            count = 0;
            e.Handled = true; // this bit fixes it
        }
    }
```

Comment: issues resolved with above step can you let me what was the compiler doing when it came to the e.handled line plz

Comment: basically you were clearing the textbox during the keypress event, when the event completes the new char would be written.  by saying you handled the event, the keypress is ignored (and so the newly typed character is ignored)

Comment: This still will not work as you can just copy and paste a bunch of letters. I suggest you use my method instead using the TextChanged event. Still pretty cool use of e.Handled, can come in handy for something else.

Answer (score 0):

use `textBox1.Text = "";` OR `textBox1.clear();`

This will clear your textbox.

Comment: i'm really surprised because even i thought it will work but it fails each time can we perform a screenshare as i have a g+ account and can show that its not working

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. You can just paste in a bunch of letters with Ctrl+V. Delete the KeyDown event and create a TextChanged event. This code should accomplish what you are attempting. Please tell me if there is any more details and I will add to my answer.

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (char c in textBox1.Text)
        if (!char.IsDigit(c)) { textBox1.Clear(); break; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your text box key press event your problem will be solved

```
e.handle = true;
```